# Nested parallellism in OpenMP

Tags: nested, openmp

I want to map tasks to three threads as follows:

1. Each of `taskA`, `taskB`, and `taskC` must be executed by separate threads.
2. `taskA` has subtasks `task(1)`, `task(2)`, and `task(3)`.
3. `taskB` has subtasks `task(11)`, `task(12)`, and `task(13)`.
4. `taskC` has subtasks `task(21)`, `task(22)`, and `task(23)`.
5. If any one of `taskA`, `taskB`, and `taskC` finishes and there is at least one unstarted subtask of another task, the thread associated with the finished task should steal the unstarted subtask.

I was not able to achieve this setting. All I was able to do the following MWE. In this MWE, threads do not obey the rules 2, 3, 4.

Here is my MWE:

```
double task(int taskid) {
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();   
    printf("%d/%d: taskid=%d\n", tid, nthreads, taskid);

    int i;
    double t = 1.1;
    for(i = 0; i < 10000000*taskid; i++) {
        t *= t/i;
    }
    return t;
}

double taskA() {
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();   
    printf("%s %d/%d\n", __FUNCTION__, tid, nthreads);
    double a, b, c;
    //#pragma omp parallel
    //#pragma omp single
    {
    #pragma omp task untied shared(a)
    a=task(1);
    #pragma omp task  untied shared(b)
    b=task(2);
    #pragma omp task  untied shared(c)
    c=task(3);
    }
    return a+b+c;
}

double taskB() {
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();   
    printf("%s %d/%d\n", __FUNCTION__, tid, nthreads);  
    double a, b, c;
    //#pragma omp parallel
    //#pragma omp single
    {
    #pragma omp task  untied  shared(a)
    a=task(11);
    #pragma omp task  untied  shared(b)
    b=task(12);
    #pragma omp task  untied  shared(c)
    c=task(13);
    }
    return a+b+c;
}

double taskC() {
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();   
    printf("%s %d/%d\n", __FUNCTION__, tid, nthreads);  
    double a, b, c;
    //#pragma omp parallel
    //#pragma omp single
    {
    #pragma omp task  untied  shared(a)
    a=task(21);
    #pragma omp task  untied  shared(b)
    b=task(22);
    #pragma omp task  untied  shared(c)
    c=task(23);
    }
    return a+b+c;
}
int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(3);
    double a,b,c;

    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    {
        #pragma omp task untied
        a=taskA();
        #pragma omp task untied
        b=taskB();
        #pragma omp task untied
        c=taskC();
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
    printf("%g %g %g\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled as:

```
icpc -Wall -fopenmp -O2 -o nestedomp nestedomp.c
```

Output:

```
taskC 1/3
1/3: taskid=21
taskA 2/3
taskB 0/3
0/3: taskid=23
2/3: taskid=22
1/3: taskid=1
1/3: taskid=2
2/3: taskid=3
0/3: taskid=11
1/3: taskid=12
2/3: taskid=13
```

Here, thread 0 starts processing task 23, however it must start processing 1 or 11.

Comment: Why don't you reformat this problem along the lines of the master-slave paradigm?  This would fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Dear @bam54, I would very appreciate if you can point me to an example or a solution based on the master-slave paradigm. By the way, I have an intuition about not using queues, locks, shared variables, etc which may degrade parallel performance especially on a system with 48 cores. I would prefer using only supported constructs which are supposed to perform very well.

Comment: The OpenMP construct that comes to mind is the schedule (dynamic, [, chunk]).  Could you simply lump all of the subtasks into a single list that can be iterated over?  Then you could use parallel for schedule (dynamic, [, chunk]), which would dole out portions of work to threads as they finish.  It looks like, from the code you gave, that the grouping of subtasks into tasks doesn't matter as far as their processing is concerned.

Comment: Dear @bam54, the grouped tasks have high locality of reference so they must be executed on the same core.

Answer (score 0):

You could use thread id to structure work distribution:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
{
 int tid = omp_get_thread_num();

 if (tid == 0) 
   //  Task 0
 } else if (tid == 1) {
   //  Task 1
 } else
   //  Task 2   
}
```

You can set the number of threads according to your needs and introduce nesting at the task level.